# How to recover from accidental deletion of certain files in the c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 folder (on a 64 bits OS)?

Tags: windows-8, 64-bit, .net-framework, repair

I am running Windows 8 (64 bits).

At some point while I intended to delete all the files under `c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\` I found myself attempting to delete all the files under `c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319` - long live the little difference.

Of course, I failed to delete most of them, because they were locked by the OS, but I did succeed to delete quite a few.

That is a major major bummer for me. The problem is that reinstalling .NET would not help - all the repair/install packages tell me .NET is installed and is perfectly fine.

However,some things are definitely broken. For example, running the TFS command line tool spits this:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Configuration system failed to initialize ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognized configuration section runtime. (C:\Program Files (x86)\Mi
crosoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\TF.exe.Config line 3)
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors.ThrowIfErrors(Boolean ignoreLocal)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfParseErrors(ConfigurationSchemaErrors schemaErrors)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfInitErrors()
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(String configKey)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(String configKey)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.PrepareClientConfigSystem(String sectionName)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection(String sectionName)
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.get_AppSettings()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.TFCommonUtil.GetAppSetting(String key, String defaultValue)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.VersionControlServer.get_MaxBackgroundThreads()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.CommandLine.VersionControlCommandLine.Main(String[] args)
PS C:\Dayforce\SharpTop>
```

I am in desperate need to repair my terrible blunder but I do not know how.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use the tool which removes all traces of .NET then at that point reinatall of and in the future don't try to remove it..

Comment: try DISM: http://blogs.technet.com/b/joscon/archive/2012/09/26/fixing-component-store-corruption-in-windows-8-and-windows-server-2012.aspx

Comment: Are they in your recycle bin?

Comment: [.NET Cleanup Tool](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2008/08/28/8904493.aspx) and [.NET Repair Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30135).  You can also remove it as a .NET Windows Feature then reinstall it to mimic using DISM if your unfamiliar with how to use it yourself.

Comment: @DavidPostill - I wish. No, I deleted them from the admin command prompt.

Comment: @Ramhound - I did not try the cleanup tool, but the repair tool claimed there was nothing to repair. But, please provide an answer so I could up-vote it.

Comment: @magicandre1981 - please, provide an answer so I could up-vote it.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the day I did a repair-install of Windows 8 as described here - http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/26095-repair-install-windows-8-a.html and then Windows Update and then installed .NET 4.5.2 Developer Pack.

That did it.